# The simplest way of using the coalesce operator and function calls

Tags: php

I want to simplify my PHP code, and while I find the coalesce operator extremely useful, I don't know if / how I can use it when calling a function from an object.

For example,

```
$message = $error_msg ?? 'No error message';
```

Works, but:

```
$message = $exception->getMessage() ?? 'No error message';
```

Doesn't. I end up having to resort to:

```
$message = isset($exception) ? $exception->getMessage() : 'No error message';
```

Is there any way to make something like the second line of code work, or is the third example the only way to do it?

Apologies in advance for not knowing the proper terminology for asking this kind of question. That might be why I couldn't find an answer.

**EDIT:** The code I wrote was just an example; this is a general question. For example, let's assume I have a template used both for creating and editing users. The User object has a getName() function that returns their name.

When creating a new user, the 'name' input should be empty. When editing a user, the 'name' input should be filled with the user's name. Of course, $user isn't set in the former, but it's set on the latter.

Having `<input value="<?php $user->getName() ?? '' ?>">` would be perfect, but throws an error. `<input value="<?php isset($user) ? $user->getName() : '' ?>">` works, but I find the former more readable, so I would like to know if there's a way to make it work.

I know that `$user->name ?? ''` works, but for some data functions are necessary / preferable.

Comment: What is `var_dump($exception->getMessage());`?

Answer (score 0):

the problem that ?? and ? working not as you expected;

see example:

```
<?php

$string = "";

var_dump($string ?? 'ups');  // output ""
var_dump($string ? $string : 'ups');   //output "ups"
```

The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with `isset()`. It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand. [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

so it means:

`$string ?? 'ups'` is equal to `isset($string) && $string !== null` which is true for an empty string

and

`$string ? $string : 'ups'` is equal to `$string == true ? $string : 'ups'` which is false for empty string

Comment: I'm sorry, my question doesn't seem to have been clear enough; English is not my main language and I learned PHP by myself, so it's hard for me to formulate my question in a clear way.
I'm aware of the difference you mentioned. However, let's imagine an object `$object`. `$object->variable ?? 'default'` returns `default` if `$object` is not set, but `$object->getVariable() ?? 'default'` throws an error; I was wondering if there was any way to make it work instead of having to use a ternary. I wanted to use that syntactic sugar in the latter cases as well, if possible.

Comment: you mean you whant smth like isset($object) && $object->getVariable() ?? 'default' ?

Comment: I think is better just to use ternar: isset($object) ? $object->getVariable() ?? 'default'; and that's it :)